# Python: reduce (list of strings) -> string

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, reduce

```
>>> import functools as ft
>>> bk = ft.reduce(lambda x, y: x[0] + "." + y[0], ['alfa', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta'])
>>> bk
'a.d'
>>> km = ft.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> km
10
>>> bk = ft.reduce(lambda x, y: x[0] + y[0], ['alfa', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta'])
>>> bk
'ad'
>>>
```

I expected something like 'a.b.c.d' or 'abcd'. Somehow, can't explain the results. There are similar questions here, but not quite like this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The result of executing the function passed as the first parameter, will be the first parameter to that function in the next iteration. So, your code works like this

```
lambda x, y: x[0] + "." + y[0]
```

1. When `x`, `y` are `'alfa'` and `'bravo'` respectively, `a.b`.
2. Now, `x` will be `a.b` and `y` will be `'charlie'`, so result will be `a.c`
3. Now, `x` will be `a.c` and `y` will be `'delta'`, so result will be `a.d`

That is why the result is `a.d`

To get what you wanted, take all the first characters from all the strings to form a list and join all the elements together with `.`, like this

```
print(".".join([item[0] for item in data]))
# a.b.c.d
```

**Note:** I won't prefer this way, but for the sake of completeness, you can do it with `reduce`, like this

```
data = ['alfa', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta']
print(ft.reduce(lambda x, y: x + ("." if x else "") + y[0], data, ""))
# a.b.c.d
```

Now, the last empty string will be the first value for `x` in the first iteration. And we use `.` only if `x` is not an empty string otherwise we use an empty string, so that the concatenation would give the result you wanted.

Comment: `'.'.join([item[0] for item in data])` - no need for building list in memory, better `'.'.join(item[0] for item in data)`

Comment: @KlassIvan Yes, but building a list makes `str.join` run faster.

Comment: I thought it's vice versa. Need to check

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the `reduce` the most elegant way would be to do:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

reduce(add, ['a', 'b', 'c']) # abc
```

Otherwise I think you better use the `string.join` interface:

```
''.join(['a', 'b', 'c']) # abc 
'.'.join(['a', 'b', 'c']) # a.b.c
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use a list of the first characters and add the elements to get the same result
here's an example using `map`:

```
list1 = ['alfa', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta']
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,map(lambda x:x[0],list1)))
```